# SQLAlchemy: Check if a given value is in a list

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

## The problem

In PostgreSQL, checking whether a field is in a given list is done using the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT * FROM stars WHERE star_type IN ('Nova', 'Planet');
```

**What is the SQLAlchemy equivalent for an `IN` SQL query?**

## What have I tried

### Python's `in`

```
db_session.query(Star).filter(Star.star_type in ('Nova', 'Planet'))
```

The query returns empty.

### SQLAlchemy's `or_`

```
db_session.query(Star).\
           filter(or_(
                      Star.star_type == 'Nova', 
                      Star.star_type == 'Planet'
           ))
```

This query returns the right result, but it is not elegant and hard to expand.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
db_session.query(Star).filter(Star.star_type.in_(['Nova', 'Planet']))
```

Answer (score 1):

A bad way of solving this problem (which I used successfully before finding accepted answer) is to use list comprehension:

```py
db_session.query(Star).filter(
    or_(*[Star.star_type == x for x in ['Nova', 'Planet'])
)
```