# Checking if SQLAlchemy column is in array of values (filtering)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There is the following situation:

```
>>> query.first().number in array
True

>>> query.filter(User.number in array).all()
[]
```

Conversely,

```
>>> query.filter(User.number not in array).all() == query.filter(User.number).all()
True
```

The solution to this was briefly indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30754899/1972495) to be:

```
>>> query.filter(User.number.in_(array))
```

It also works with the `func` keyword:

```
>>> query.filter(func.date(User.date).in_(array))
```

Could someone explain why?

Comment: Python's data model defines the return value of `__contains__` as a boolean, and [`in` will in fact convert](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) anything returned by a custom implementation to such, so it cannot be used to produce SQLA constructs like some of the other dunders/ops can.

Comment: In addition of course `__contains__` is defined in the context of the *container*, so in this case the `array`, not `User.number`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50655959/python-in-operator-reflected-magic-method